# VMware Workstation 7 build 203739 - Capture Movie Mouse Pointer Not Visible

Tags: windows-vista, vmware-workstation

I have noticed that whenever I create a Capture Movie, the movie is fine but the mouse pointer is not visible at all.

The clicks are on buttons file menus are executed but is hard for a viewer of the capture movie session to follow the recording smoothly. This was not a problem in previous versions of WorkStation.

Is this a bug or is there a setting I can set to see the mouse pointer? Note: VM Tools are installed, the host is Vista Ultimate Edition SP1, x64 and the guest is Windows XP SP2.

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable the hardware acceleration (set it to none) from the troubleshooting tab in the monitor properties by doing the below instructions in the guest OS (XP)

1- Right click in the desktop
2- Settings tab
3- Advanced
4- Troubleshooting
5- Hardware acceleration ===> none